# Are 'eye' bifurcations possible?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, stability-in-odes, fixed-points, bifurcation

I am currently studying bifurcations in dynamical systems and have seen saddle-node, transcritical and pitchfork bifurcations. My question is can you have a system which has an 'eye-shaped' bifurcation diagram, where there are 2 saddle or pitchfork bifurcations opposite each other, i.e. 2 fixed points appear and then disappear; or 1 changes to 3 and back as a parameter $µ$ changes?